# SQL ExecuteScalar 2 return values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to return a concatenation of 2 values from a sql query. I search the database for nom and prenom and would like to return them as

```
prenom+" "+nom
```

However, when I execute the following, all I get in returnValue is

```
nom
```

Code:

```
SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection();
MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SearchConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand();
searchCommand.CommandText = "select nom,prenom from [reference].[dbo].[v_employe] where compagnie like @compagnie and no_employe like @num";
searchCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
searchCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@compagnie", this.REComboboxSearch.Value);
SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@num", this.RESearchId.Value);

searchCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);
searchCommand.Parameters.Add(p2);

MyConnection.Open();

returnValue = (String)searchCommand.ExecuteScalar();

MyConnection.Close();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you trying to concatenate them? I only see `select nom,prenom from`

Comment: From the schema and the escaping of identifiers I rather think it's sql server and not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
searchCommand.CommandText = "select nom + ' ' + prenom as c_nom from [reference].[dbo].[v_employe] where compagnie like @compagnie and no_employe like @num";
```

instead to get the concatenated name in just one column.

The method `ExecuteScalar()` returns only the first column of the row, so you've got to concatenate your name in the query itself.